# How to add a new line after a column in sql query Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, newline, concatenation, oracle-apex, linefeed

I'm running the following sql query in my Oracle Apex application:

```
SELECT column1 || chr(13) || chr(10) || column2 FROM table;
```

I want the second column to be displayed on a new line. This doesn't seems to be working in my Apex application. However it's working on SQL*PLUS.

Any ideas what could be the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: So, where do you need this output? In the SQL Command window or in a report on a page?

Comment: I want it in a report on one of my pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is change the display type of the the column to "Standard Report Column" and change your query to

```
SELECT column 1 || '<br/>' || column2 FROM table;
```

However, you'll have to be sure that your data won't contain valid HTML or characters, because  things like `&gt;` would convert to >

Comment: Can anyone tell me what if i had to do the same thing but on the SQL command window instead of apex report?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible. The command window sends the query straight to the SQL Engine, which doesn't know how to interpret a new line character.
If this is just for testing purposes, you might be better off doing this in SQL+.